# Не выводит построчно текст TextMesh

Tags: c#, unity3d, циклы

Показывает только 9.

```
public GameObject go;
void ShowText(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                go.GetComponent<TextMesh> ().text = i + "\n";
    }
```

А если сделать вот так, то выводит со следующей строкой:

```
void ShowText(){
// работает
go.GetComponent<TextMesh> ().text = "HereText\nHereTextToo";
// работает тоже
go.GetComponent<TextMesh> ().text = "HereText" + "\n" + "HereTextToo";
        }
```

Как получить столбик от 0 до 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты перезаписываешь свою строку каждую итерацию.

```
    void ShowText()
    {
        var tm =  go.GetComponent<TextMesh> ();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
               tm.text += i + "\n";
    }
```